# How can i change my const char pointer to unique pointer?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

So I am trying to change my game and I found a problem where I couldn't make the change:

I have the following code:

```
    std::string fileContents = "";
  const char* contentsPtr = fileContents.c_str();
```

I tried making it:

```
const std::unique_ptr<char> contentsPtr = fileContents.c_str();
```

It doesn't work since there is no constructor to make the conversion from char*
to unique_ptr so how can I make this change?

Comment: The pointer returned by `c_str()` is not up for grabs, it's owned by `fileContents`. You can't just shove it in a `unique_ptr` and let it own it. Why do you even think you need a `unique_ptr` in your case?

Comment: It is not about need it is about me wanting to use it, I am working on a project that we not supposed to use "naked pointers".

Comment: In that case, why have `contentsPtr` at all? What does your code use it for?

Comment: @Ninhow Explain what you really need to do. *Why* are you not supposed to use naked pointers? It's error-prone? It's inefficient? It looks ugly? It's hard to understand?

Comment: @Ninhow - That's not a bad goal in general. But one should not be going about it by way of cargo cult programming.

Comment: The question to ask is who owns the data. In this case it's fileContents. Smart pointers own the data and you cannot have more than one owner. Multiple shared pointers can share ownership with each other, but not with something else. You may want to watch https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE

Comment: Yes, I understand it, what you want me to say? I asked help about how to do it and now I know it is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not want a unique_ptr around any resource you **do not own**. In this case the pointer returned from `c_str()`. It still belongs to fileContents objects. If/when you get past actually getting a unique_ptr around c_str(), then you later have memory corruption.